# IOE Exception was unhandled by User Code

Tags: asp.net, soap, sugarcrm

I am getting this exception

### **IOE Exception was unhandled by User Code**

**Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.**

for this line code:

```
  //Try to authenticate
  SugarCRM.entry_value LoginResult = SugarClient.login(UserAuth, "SoapTest", LoginList);
```

[Click here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/100Web_Services/100Soap_API/100Examples/100CSharp/Logging_In_-_SOAP_and_C%23) for complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the problem.i didn't gave correct url of my configured AMP account.due to which it was throwing errot and as i was not handling it,i got that exception.

So make sure you check all three parameters Username,Password and InstanceUrl correctly if you get such exception.